# How to check if a particular string in one array is in another array

Tags: c, binary-search

I have an array called puzzle which consist of words/letters/random strings and I want to check if it has any of the same strings in another array called dictionary (the strings in dictionary are listed in alphabetical order)

So I believe my problem is the binary search in my program, I'm not entire sure how to work around it using strings. I tried to use some strcmp() but I don't think thats the way to go?

When the program runs, it gets no output. that there is no matches but there are.

here is my binary search function:

```
int binsearch(char **dictionary, char *puzzle) {
    int start = 1;  //excluded first string of dictionary array bc #
    int end = listlength;
    while (start < end) {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        int temp = strcmp(dictionary[mid], puzzle);
        if (temp < 0) {
            start = mid + 1; //it is in upper half
        } else
        if (temp > 0) {  //check lower half
            end = mid;
        } else
            return 1; //found a match hopefully
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and my entire code is here if maybe something you need to see

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define listlength 149256
#define maxWordLen 19

char **getWords(int rows, int cols);
void freeArray(char **array, int rows);
char **makeGridArray(int rows, int cols);
int binsearch(char **dictionary, char *puzzle);
void wordSearch(char **dictionary, char **puzzle, int row, int col);
const int DX_SIZE = 8;
const int DX[] = { -1, -1, -1,  0,  0,  1,  1,  1 };
const int DY[] = { -1,  0,  1, -1,  1, -1,  0,  1 };

int main() {

    //read in dictionary
    int i, j, x = 0, numCases, gridRow, gridCol;
    char **words = getWords(listlength, maxWordLen);

    //Get number of cases.
    printf("enter number of cases:\n");
    scanf("%d", &numCases);

    //process each case.
    while (x < numCases) {
        scanf("%d%d", &gridRow, &gridCol);

        //make word search grid
        char **grid = makeGridArray(gridRow + 1, gridCol);

        /* for testing if grid is storing properly
        for (i = 0; i < gridRow + 1; i++) {
            printf("%s\n", grid[i]);
        }
        */

        printf("Words Found Grid #%d:\n", x + 1);
        wordSearch(words, grid, gridRow + 1, gridCol);
        x++;
        freeArray(grid, gridRow + 1);
    }
    freeArray(words, listlength);
}

char **getWords(int rows, int cols) {
    int i;

    //allocate top level of pointers.
    char **words = malloc(sizeof(char*) * rows);

    //allocate each individual array
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        words[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * cols + 1);
    }

    //read dictionary.txt
    FILE *dictionary = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        fgets(words[i], cols + 1,dictionary);
    }
    fclose(dictionary);
    return words;
}

char **makeGridArray(int rows, int cols) {
    //allocate top level of pointers.
    char **grid = malloc(sizeof(char*) * rows);
    int i, j;

    //allocate each individual array
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        grid[i] = malloc(sizeof(char) * cols + 1);
    }
    //read in user input grid
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        gets(grid[i]);
    }
    return grid;
}

int binsearch(char **dictionary, char *puzzle) {
    int start = 1;  //excluded first string of dictionary array bc #
    int end = listlength;
    while (start < end) {
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        int temp = strcmp(dictionary[mid], puzzle);
        if (temp < 0) {
            start = mid + 1; //it is in upper half
        } else
        if (temp > 0) {  //check lower half
            end = mid;
        } else
            return 1; //found a match hopefully
    }
    return 0;
}

void wordSearch(char **dictionary, char **puzzle, int row, int col) {
    int i, X, Y, dir;
    char wordsfound[19] = { '\0' };
    for (X = 0; X < row + 1; X++) {
        for (Y = 0; Y < col; Y++) {
            for (dir = 0; dir < DX_SIZE; dir++) //check every direction
                for (i = 0; i < 19; i++) {
                    //will continue in direction DX,DY starting at x,y
                    int nextX = X + DX[dir] * i;
                    int nextY = Y + DY[dir] * i;
                    if (nextX < 0 || nextX >= row) break; //keep in bounds
                    if (nextY < 0 || nextY >= col) break;
                    //store the string of letters to check
                    wordsfound[i] = (puzzle[nextX][nextY]);
                    if (i > 3) { //minimum word is 4
                        wordsfound[i + 1] = '\0';
                        //if the string of letters is actually a word, print
                        int bin = binsearch(dictionary, wordsfound);
                        if (bin) {
                            printf("%s\n", wordsfound);
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
    return;
}

void freeArray(char **array, int rows) {
    //free arrays
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        free(array[i]);
    }
    free(array);
}
```

Comment: There is no array in your code. A pointer is not an array.

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate? no array in binsearch function? am i not correctly passing my array into the function?

Comment: A pointer is not called "array" because it is none! Note this does not imply your code is wrong there. You cannout pass an array to a function in C.

Comment: yes, I tried passing a 2d array with pointers. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You do not have a 2D array. Not even a "pointer to the first entry of one"! A 2D array is something like `int a[2][3]`! And **that** is not the same as an `int **`!

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying do here?   wordsfound[i] = (puzzle[nextX][nextY]);
This only assigna character to the wordsfound. Are you trying to assign a specific char?

Comment: In whole, I'm trying to make a word search program. I'm having trouble with checking if the grid has words in it by using a dictionary.txt file to verify my words.

Comment: Before it reaches the binary search function, I printed out the array that is suppose to be collecting the strings/words and it indeed collects the words but in the program it will only print them if any of its strings matches any in the dictionary. but it prints nothing so i assume it is not figuring out whether or not any match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the `getwords()` function: you read the words from the dictionary with `fgets()` but forget to remove the trailing `\n`.  All words in the dictionary have a trailing `\n`, so none of them match your searches.

Here is a corrected version:

```
char **getWords(int rows, int cols) {
    char line[256];
    int i;

    //allocate top level of pointers.
    char **words = malloc(sizeof(char*) * rows);

    //read dictionary.txt
    FILE *dictionary = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        if (!fgets(line, sizeof line, dictionary))
            line[0] = '\0';
        line[strcspn(line, "\n")] = '\0';
        words[i] = strdup(line);
    }
    fclose(dictionary);
    return words;
}
```

Note that it would be better not to rely on a known *magical* listlength.  You could also ignore comment and empty lines while reading the dictionary.

Comment: oh didn't even realize that, thank you. and in regards to listlength, I should code it so that it can work on a general basis so it can be adjusted to fit any number, yes? 

also, I changed the getwords function i still can't produce any output of matched strings :/

Comment: @Hispazn: is the dictionary in the same case as the problem?  As in lowercase dictionary and uppercase boggle problem...

Comment: @Hispazn: The test for minimum word length is incorrect, it should be `if (i >= 3) { //minimum word is 4`

Comment: @Hispazn: `wordsfound` should be 1 byte longer and does not need to be initialized: `char wordsfound[20];`

Comment: @Hispazn: why do you make the array `gridRow + 1`rows instead of just `gridRow`?

Comment: wow *facepalm*.. makes sense since what I was using to test the program had a max of 4 length words.

Comment: I originally had it just gridRow but for some reason it kept cutting off the last line, as a quick fix i just decided to add 1 so it could completely read it in without trying to see the real problem just so i could test other parts of the program

Comment: thank you so much, it finally works just because of that simple i >= 3 (at least for the example i was testing, even tho it would have worked on larger words)

Comment: @Hispazn: Note that using `gets()` to read the puzzle is risky, but you cannot read the puzzle line directly with `fgets`: you need to give it a larger buffer for the `\n`.  The simple solution is to allocate the puzzle rows to 21 bytes and ignore the last column (19) that should be all `\n`.